# Output AVI file without interleaving

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to encode videos to have them play on a little video recording tablet, but it's very picky about the format. Here's an example file that was recorded by the device itself:

```
ffmpeg -i AMSG0003.AVI
ffmpeg version N-94646-g1cfba7fc75 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.101 / 58. 55.101
  libavformat    58. 31.102 / 58. 31.102
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.101 /  7. 58.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[avi @ 0000021e58ac8480] non-interleaved AVI
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'AMSG0003.AVI':
  Duration: 00:00:48.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2472 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline) (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 2253 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_u8 ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 24000 Hz, mono, u8, 192 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

Note the `[avi @ 0000021e58ac8480] non-interleaved AVI`.
Even if I do `ffmpeg -i AMSG0003.AVI -acodec copy -vcodec copy -fflags +bitexact AMSG0004.AVI`, the result changes from bitrate 2472kb/s to 2453kb/s, from length 48.27s to 48.17s, the message about "non-interleaved AVI" is not present and, most importantly, the file won't work when copied back to the device.

Is there any way to get ffmpeg to create a non-interleaved AVI?

Answer (score 0):

No. Audio Video **Interleaved** files are expected to be interleaved. Files otherwise are spec deviations.

Comment: Do you know with certainty that FFMPEG does not have any way whatsoever to do this? Or did you just assume that that's the case?

Comment: Yes, ffmpeg cannot write sequential streams in an AVI.